# How to exclude ActiveMQ from Thorntail

Tags: activemq-artemis, thorntail

How to remove ActiveMQ Artemis dependency from Thorntail 2.5.0.Final? I believe this must be done on `pom.xml` using `<exclusion>`, but I don't know what to exclude.

We use JMS but not ActiveMQ. The idea here is trying to improve performance, even a little bit.

Any clue on how to achieve this?

**Edit1**:
We want to remove it because it looks like it is stealing memory (according to the log):

```
2021-02-25 15:55:58,315 | INFO  | [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] | (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45::) | AMQ221057: Global Max Size is being adjusted to 1/2 of the JVM max size (-Xmx)
```

**Edit 2**:
We also tried to add this snipet to `project-defaults.yml`, but it apparently didn't work (all the activemq log entrances remain there).

```
  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        active: false
```

**Edit 3**:
`project-defaults.yml` (irrelevant parts were ommited)

```
thorntail:
  http:
    port: 8080

  resource-adapters:
    resource-adapters:
      GenericJMS:
        archive: generic-jms-ra.rar
        transaction-support: XATransaction
        connection-definitions:
          TibcoPool:
            class-name: org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsManagedConnectionFactory
            jndi-name: ${jms.connectionFactoryJndiName}
            config-properties:
              ConnectionFactory:
                value: ${jms.connectionFactoryName}
              UserName:
                value: ${jms.user}
              Password:
                value: ${jms.password}
              JndiParameters:
                value: java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.tibco.tibjms.naming;java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://${jms.host}:7222;java.naming.security.principal=${jms.user};java.naming.security.credentials=${jms.password}
            min-pool-size: 1
            max-pool-size: 5
            blocking-timeout-wait-millis: 30000
            idle-timeout-minutes: 5
            xa-resource-timeout: 300
            security:
              application:

  ejb3:
    default-resource-adapter-name: GenericJMS
    thread-pools:
      default:
        max-threads: ${env.EJB_DEFAULT_THREAD_POOL_MAX_THREADS:10}

  ee:
    global-modules: com.tibco.tibjms
    jboss-descriptor-property-replacement: true
    annotation-property-replacement: true

  deployment:
    org.jboss.genericjms.tibco:generic-jms-ra.rar:

  messaging-activemq:
    servers:
      default:
        active: false
```

`pom.xml` (irrelevant parts were ommited):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <thorntail.version>2.5.0.Final</thorntail.version>
        <thorntail.version.maven.plugin>2.5.0.Final</thorntail.version.maven.plugin>
        <version.httpclient>4.5.9</version.httpclient>
        <jms.ra.version>2.0.1.Final</jms.ra.version>
        <jms.tibco.version>8.3.0.015</jms.tibco.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>${thorntail.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Thorntail dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmx</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-remote</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>messaging</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>resource-adapters</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger</artifactId>
            <version>${thorntail.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${version.httpclient}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.23</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- TIBCO -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.genericjms.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>generic-jms-ra</artifactId>
            <version>${jms.ra.version}</version>
            <type>rar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibcrypt</artifactId>
            <version>${jms.tibco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tibco</groupId>
            <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
            <version>${jms.tibco.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.0.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>my-project</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.thorntail</groupId>
                <artifactId>thorntail-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${thorntail.version.maven.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                    <useUberJar>true</useUberJar>

                    <properties>
                        <use-deployment-logging-config>false</use-deployment-logging-config>
                        <jms.connectionFactoryName>XAQueueConnectionFactory</jms.connectionFactoryName>
                        <jms.connectionFactoryJndiName>java:/${jms.connectionFactoryName}</jms.connectionFactoryJndiName>
                        <jms.connectionFactoryClass>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsManagedConnectionFactory</jms.connectionFactoryClass>
                        <jms.user>user</jms.user>
                        <jms.password>password</jms.password>
                        <jms.host>NN.NN.NN.NN</jms.host>
                        <jms.jndiParameters>java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.tibco.tibjms.naming;java.naming.factory.initial=com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory;java.naming.provider.url=tcp://${jms.host}:7222;java.naming.security.principal=${jms.user};java.naming.security.credentials=${jms.password}</jms.jndiParameters>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: That unfortunately isn't possible. To be able to use JMS, the `messaging-activemq` subsystem must be present. You can try using the `ejb-mdb` fraction instead of `messaging`, but the only actual difference is that with this fraction, you can't configure a messaging broker -- but the code is still present

Comment: @Ladicek is it possible to disable it, at least? I tried it setting the "active" to "false", with no success.

Comment: I see edits in the question: pretty sure ActiveMQ Artemis isn't stealing half of your heap, it just autoconfigures some limits. How do you use JMS? Installing your own resource adapter for connecting to an external broker? In that case, the `ejb-mdb` fraction is what you look for: https://docs.thorntail.io/2.7.0.Final/#_ejb_mdb